# MVC em C# como funciona as declarações

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho o código abaixo, e para chama a session que guarda os dados do usuário, somente uma vez quero colocar ela na declaração do controller.

#### Dúvida

A variável `usuarioLogado` é por requisição ou pode acontecer que o usuário X chama o controller e no meio o usuário Y chama o mesmo controller, e `usuarioLogado` troca de informações, aonde deveria estar lendo usuário X, passo a ter o usuário Y.

#### Código

```
public class AppRequisitoController : Controller
{
    string controller = "AppRequisito";
    UsuarioLogadoDTO usuarioLogado = Services.UsuarioService.SessaoUsuarioLogado();

    private void Listagem(Conexao db)
    {   
        var repAppRequisito = new AppRequisitoRepositorio(db);
        ViewBag.ListaAppRequisito = repAppRequisito.ComboBox(usuarioLogado);
    }
```

#### Sessão do Usuário

```
public static UsuarioLogadoDTO SessaoUsuarioLogado()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Session[Constantes.sessaoUsuarioLogado] as UsuarioLogadoDTO;
}
```

Comment: O que faz `Services.UsuarioService.SessaoUsuarioLogado();`?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez editei a pergunta.

Comment: Não acho uma boa você usar `Session` para obter o usuário logado. Melhor usar a informação do provedor de autenticação. `Session` não é consistente 100% do tempo em aplicação sem estados como as que são escritas em ASP.NET MVC. Esse código vai parar de funcionar com bastante frequência.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez teria algum exemplo de provedor de autenticação?

Comment: Membership, Identity... não sei o que você tá usando.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez estou usando Membership

Answer (score 2):

Interações em aplicações web podem ser *Stateless* ou *Statefull*, ou seja, ele não mantém estados da aplicação ou mantém o controle do estado das interações. Em requisições *Stateless* os estados são mantidos no cliente, através de cookies ou de outra forma, sempre de forma encriptada.

Uma Session por outro lado mantém o estado no servidor diferente do cookie, sendo assim *Statefull*, ela funciona da seguinte forma, a sua aplicação cria uma chave que referência os dados que são mantidos temporariamente no servidor. Então ele envia um cookie ou outra forma de autenticação para o cliente, que referência o dado armazenado no servidor.

Então não ocorreria o caso do usuário receber dados de uma session de outro usuário, porque ela é referenciada por essa chave única.

Comment: Tá um pouco esquisito isso que você falou. Sessions é uma coisa. Cookies é outra. Sessions sim admite um estado transiente, mantido em servidor. Cookies é um recurso em que uma informação é anotada em cliente e nada tem a ver com estados. Ela pode ajudar a recriar um estado, mas isso não é obrigatório.

Comment: Sim, eu não falei que Session e Cookie é a mesma coisa, elas são diferentes. O gerenciamento da Session pode ser implementada através de cookies já que a chave para referenciar os dados no servidor tem que estar no cliente. Não sei como eu posso deixar esse posicionamento mais claro, qual parte você achou confusa para que eu possa melhorar a resposta?

Comment: A segunda frase. Parece que são a mesma coisa.

Comment: Uma última coisa (tá bem boa já): `Sessions` não são *stateless*. Simplesmente não há manutenção de estado, diferente de `Cookies`, que este sim pode ser considerado parcialmente *stateless* porque você pode recriar o estado pelo código da aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

Sempre é por requisição. Isso não se aplica apenas para o ASP.NET MVC, é assim que funciona uma aplicação web.

Basicamente, não se mantém nenhum estado do lado do servidor. Por isso se usa estratégias como *cookies* para se simular este tipo de coisa, os *cookies* são enviados em todas as requisições e tratados no servidor.